# Javascript call Remove() twice to remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a weird event where I must call remove() twice to remove an element. Below I've pasted my javascript console, you can see that I need to call remove twice to remove the element.

```
$("#products-view-17")
[
<div class=​"product-tile" id=​"products-view-17">​…​</div>​
]

$("#products-view-17").remove()
[
<div class=​"product-tile" id=​"products-view-17">​
<a href=​"http:​/​/​www.shopify.com" target=​"_blank">​…​</a>​
<div id=​"associate_form" class=​"remove_button">​…​</div>​
</div>​
]

$("#products-view-17")
[
<div class=​"product-tile" id=​"products-view-17">​
<a href=​"http:​/​/​www.shopify.com" target=​"_blank">​…​</a>​
<div id=​"associate_form" class=​"remove_button">​…​</div>​
</div>​
]

$("#products-view-17").remove()
[
<div class=​"product-tile" id=​"products-view-17">​
<a href=​"http:​/​/​www.shopify.com" target=​"_blank">​…​</a>​
<div id=​"associate_form" class=​"remove_button">​…​</div>​
</div>​
]

$("#products-view-17")
[]
```

Other elements on my page have no problem, one Remove() call does it. Only those that are dynamic generated here are problematic. This used to work fine, what could possible have broken it?

Comment: Two elements with the same ID? The `"#products-view-17"` selector will select only the first one if there are multiple.

Comment: @cookiemonster thats what i thought originally, i checked page source and was only able to find that ID once

Comment: If the problematic ones are dynamically generated, how are you verifying by checking the page source?

Comment: ...try this before you do a remove: `$("[id=products-view-17]").length`

Comment: sorry, i meant dynamic generated as in I loop through multiple products before the page is generated. E.g "#products-view-1", "#products-view-12", "#products-view-19"

Comment: @cookiemonster returned 2! the question now is, how is that possible? thanks! very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a problem with the library as mentioned by you.Check the following work around for removing multiple elements with same id

```
 $('[id^="products-view-17"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There was in fact two elements of the exact same ID. Although only one copy on the page, this is the culprit: https://github.com/okendoken/bootstrap-tabcollapse